# Android - Widget Disappears immediately when placed

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I'm trying to add a widget into my app and I am facing a problem. Whenever I grab the widget and place it on my homescreen, it just disappears. I can only see it for about 0.5 seconds. Here is the code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider" >
   <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
   </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
      android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
      android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

**MyWidgetProvider.java**

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


     @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    //IDs
    for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
      // Create data
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app_preferences", 0);
      int number = prefs.getInt("progress", 0);

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.appwidget);
      Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));

      // Set the text
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widgettext, String.valueOf(number));

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgettext, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, remoteViews);
      Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  }
}
```

**appwidget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/widgetlayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/widgetimage" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgettext"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**widget_info.xml**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:minWidth="120dp"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget"
android:previewImage="@drawable/widgetimage"
android:configure="com.example.app.widget.MyWidgetProvider" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

you can see the last line of the java file contains a toast. This toast actually gets called and there are no errors whatsoever in the logcat.

Thanks!

Comment: anyone knows an answer?

Comment: Have you actually added a configuration activity for this: android:configure="com.example.app.widget.MyWidgetProvider". If not, the OS will likely consider the configuration was cancelled.

Comment: Yes, Its in the widget_info.xml, last line.

Answer (score 1):

You're android:configure element must refer to an activity that will allow configuration of your widget. This activity must set result to RESULT_OK, otherwise configuration is cancelled and widget is removed.

I suppose referring to your widget provider, not an activity, has the same effect of returning RESULT_CANCEL from the configuration activity.

If you don't have a configuration activity, simply remove this entry and the widget will be added without trying to open such.

Comment: I will look at this when I get back home, thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing OP never made it home. RIP Sam!?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility other than 3c71's answer is that you might have forgotten to use the two-parameter version of `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)`.  The `data` parameter has to include an EXTRA which identifies the widget ID.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The widget ID is provided to the configuration activity as an EXTRA in the Intent that is supplied to the activity when it is called.  Retrieve it and store it like this:

```
mAppWidgetId = getIntent().getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,     AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```